# Can't add another node from primary node with MongoDB replication set

Tags: mongodb, centos-7

On CentOS 7.

MongoDB version: 3.2.15

There are two nodes:

- node1
- node2

## node1

### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 node1
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.0.100              node1
192.168.0.101              node2
```

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /mongo-metadata
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.100  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


security:
  keyFile: /root/keyfile

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs0

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

## node2

### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 node2
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.0.100              node1
192.168.0.101              node2
```

### /etc/mongod.conf

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /mongo-metadata
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.101  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


security:
  keyFile: /root/keyfile

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs0

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

## Run mongo command on node1

```
mongo
rs.initiate()
use admin
db.createUser(...)
db.auth('admin', '...')
rs.add('node2')
```

Caused error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: node1:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: node2:27017 failed with No route to host",
    "code" : 74
}
```

Is it can't connect to node2 from node1? Is there a official guide about how to do mongodb replication set?

Comment: The [`net.bindIp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) value should be a comma-separated list if you want to provide multiple values. Try: `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.101`. There may also be an issue with firewall configuration. The MongoDB documentation has a good guide to security measures, including examples of firewall configuration: [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/).

Comment: @Stennie Thank you. Have fixed the issue. Added iptables rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple. You have not open your firewall for port 27017, is must be done on both nodes.

And asked documentation can be found [here!](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)

Comment: Thank you. That's the reason. I add this: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT` and save the iptables: `service iptables save` on each node. But still the same error. I tried to ping `ping node2:27017` from node1, got error: `Don't know the name or the service.`

Comment: telnet node2 27017 should give you answer, if port is open AND there is mongod waiting..  Remove bindIp -line from config, so mongod listen all interfaces

Comment: Check your iptables. Run command `iptables-save` and check that your ACCEPT rule of port 27017 is NOT after DROP rule what would catch that 27017

Comment: After I flush all chains of iptables: `iptables -F`, and add `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT`, saved it: `service iptables save`. It works! Thank you very much for your kindly help!